# Is it possible to assign a reserved IP to an azure web app for outbound traffic

Tags: networking, security, azure

I have 3 Azure web apps, one being an API app that makes API calls out to a client network. They need to add for security reasons one known reserved (owned  exclusively) IP address. Can this be done without buying an expensive azure firewall, or ASE (which ends up with a firewall as part of it) ?
Rgds
Frustrated admin!

Answer (score 0):

[Assign a static public IP to the virtual machine.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses) Possibly from a [public IP address prefix.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/public-ip-address-prefix) If you use other Azure services like web apps, funnel it through some gateway, like the firewall with SNAT you were trying to avoid.

Consider complaining to the maintainer of the API service. One static IP address is not normal for many cloud apps.